# A permutation preserving algebraic relations between roots defines a unique element of the Galois group

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

I'm studying Galois theory using James Milne's notes (available [here](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ft.html)) and I've had difficulties understanding the following passage:

---

[image]

---

Specifically, my question is:

- **How does condition (8) exactly ensure that the map $\alpha_i\mapsto\sigma\alpha_i$ is an $F$-homomorphism?**

I understand that since $F_f$ is the splitting field of $f$, any $F$-homomorphism $F_f\rightarrow F_f$ is necessarily an $F$-isomorphism, and thus, the permutation extends to an element of the Galois group. However, before that, we need to verify that $\widetilde{\sigma}:\alpha_i\mapsto\sigma\alpha_i$ is indeed an $F$-homomorphism. My only idea to prove this was the following:

---

Given elements $\alpha,\beta\in F_f$, there exist $g,h\in F[X_1,...,X_n]$ such that $\alpha=g(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ and $\beta=h(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$. So, if $p\in F[X_1,...,X_n]$ is the product $gh$, we have $p(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)-g(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)h(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)=0$. Using (8), we get $p(\sigma\alpha_1,...,\sigma\alpha_n)-g(\sigma\alpha_1,...,\sigma\alpha_n)h(\sigma\alpha_1,...,\sigma\alpha_n)=0$. As $p(\sigma\alpha_1,...,\sigma\alpha_n)=\widetilde{\sigma}(\alpha\beta)$, $g(\sigma\alpha_1,...,\sigma\alpha_n)=\widetilde{\sigma}(\alpha)$, and $h(\sigma\alpha_1,...,\sigma\alpha_n)=\widetilde{\sigma}(\beta)$, this shows that $\widetilde{\sigma}(\alpha\beta)=\widetilde{\sigma}(\alpha)\widetilde{\sigma}(\beta)$.

---

I have the impression that this might not be the "right" (or most natural) way to use condition (8), and I also would like to understand better the author's reasoning at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me rephrase the argument in terms that are hopefully easier to understand. We want to show that a permutation $\sigma \in \operatorname{Sym}(\{\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n\})$ obeying (8) extends to an element $\widetilde{\sigma}$ of the Galois group.

The roots $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n$ generate the splitting field $F_f$. This means that any element in $F_f$ can be written as an algebraic combination of the roots, so the evaluation map
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{ev}_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} \, \colon F[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to F_f \, ; \quad \operatorname{ev}_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}}(g) = g(\boldsymbol{\alpha}),
\end{equation}
where $\boldsymbol{\alpha} = (\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_n)$, is a surjective $F$-homomorphism.

Similarly, we may also consider the permuted roots $\boldsymbol{\beta} = (\sigma \alpha_1, \ldots, \sigma \alpha_n)$ and the corresponding surjective evaluation map
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{ev}_{\beta} \, \colon F[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to F_f \, ; \quad \operatorname{ev}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}}(g) = g(\boldsymbol{\beta}).
\end{equation}

The condition in (8) simply states that $\ker \operatorname{ev}_{\boldsymbol{\alpha}} \subseteq \ker \operatorname{ev}_{\boldsymbol{\beta}}$. Then by the fundamental homomorphism theorem, one may write $\operatorname{ev}_{\beta} = \widetilde{\sigma} \circ \operatorname{ev}_\alpha$, where $\widetilde{\sigma} \colon F_f \to F_f$ is a surjective $F$-homomorphism, which is simply an $F$-automorphism. In other words, evaluation at $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ is given by applying some automorphism $\widetilde{\sigma}$ to the evaluation at $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$; this is the desired extension of the permutation $\sigma$.

Indeed, substituting $x_i$ into the equality $\operatorname{ev}_{\beta} = \widetilde{\sigma} \circ \operatorname{ev}_\alpha$ yields that $\widetilde{\sigma}(\alpha_i) = \sigma \alpha_i.$